# Creating a .txt file with the "with open" function, but it lands in the root directory from databricks

Tags: python, databricks

Creating a .txt file but it lands in the os

I want to get the stackoverflow.txt file into the databricks filestore dbfs.

```
%python
with open('stackoverflow.txt', 'w') as f:
f.write("Dear sir, I am a Prince in a far kingdom you have not heard of.  I want to send you money via wire transfer so please ...\n")
f.write("YOUR COMPUTER HAS BEEN INFECTED!  YOU MUST RESET YOUR PASSWORD.  Reply to this email with your password and SSN ...\n"

import os
os.listdir()
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the full path to the desired location, instead of just the filename, to `open()`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it didn't work. The file still did not end up in the dbfs.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Where did the file end up instead?

Comment: I got the following error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs:/stackoverflow.txt'

Comment: Add example of what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dbutils](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html):

```
dbutils.fs.put("dbfs:/FileStore/stackoverflow.txt", "This is a file in cloud storage.")
```

Or with [local file API](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-apis) (non-community edition only). With local file api, make sure you are prefixing with `/dbfs/` to store stuff in dbfs.

```
with open('/dbfs/FileStore/stackoverflow.txt','w+') as f:
    f.write('This is a file in cloud storage...')
```

You can use `dbutils.fs.ls("dbfs:/")` to check on your written files.

Comment: 2nd option won’t work on community edition

Comment: gotcha. will update answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why it didn't work. After switching from the community edition to the paid version, the file was written to the correct directory, namely the Databricks Filestore, using:

```
with open('/dbfs/FileStore/stackoverflow.txt','w+') as f:
f.write('This is a file in cloud storage...')
```

Comment: /dbfs doesn’t work on community edition with DBR 7.x/8.x

Answer (score 0):

If you have small data files on your local machine that you want to analyze with Databricks, you can import them to DBFS using the UI. https://docs.databricks.com/data/data.html

Another option is to use the DBFS command-line interface (CLI) which uses the DBFS API to expose an easy to use command-line interface to DBFS. Using this client, you can interact with DBFS using commands similar to those you use on a Unix command line.

```
# List files in DBFS
dbfs ls
# Put local file ./apple.txt to dbfs:/apple.txt
dbfs cp ./apple.txt dbfs:/apple.txt
# Get dbfs:/apple.txt and save to local file ./apple.txt
dbfs cp dbfs:/apple.txt ./apple.txt
# Recursively put local dir ./banana to dbfs:/banana
dbfs cp -r ./banana dbfs:/banana
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am using the Databricks Community Edition. Could it be possible that this is the problem? I cant get access to the token, so i cant configure the command-line interface.